# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object angular

Tags: angular

How to solve: **TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object**

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Object.assertWorkspaceValidity (C:\Users\albert.williams\Documents\GitHub\alpha-ui\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\core\assert-workspace-validity.js:8:35)
    at Object.createProjectGraph (C:\Users\albert.williams\Documents\GitHub\alpha-ui\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\core\project-graph\project-graph.js:17:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\albert.williams\Documents\GitHub\alpha-ui\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\command-line\run-one.js:19:46)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\albert.williams\Documents\GitHub\alpha-ui\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:62)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: To be able to help you please post the provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g., on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)